# How to activate notebook function keys?

Tags: 10.10, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

I have upgraded my "Compaq Presarion CQ60" notebook from Ubuntu 10.04 to 10.10.

Everything is fine, but the functional keys for brightness <kbd>F7</kbd> & <kbd>F8</kbd> are not working. It was well working with 10.04.How to solve this?

Comment: Does the brightness slider in System ▸ Preferences ▸ Power Management work? Can you use one of [these methods](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LaptopTestingTeam/Old/HotkeyResearch) to find out the keycodes for your brightness keys?

Answer (score 1):

Generally to activate any special function keys on your keyboard you need to choose your "model" from the keyboard section of the preferences menu.

your model should be listed under Compaq.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks to both aendruk and allan.There in Power management no change was happening on adjusting the brightness.But I followed what Allan told and it is working well.

Comment: I remember a while back hearing about redshift which auto adjusts the screen brightness depending on the time of day and I found it http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/07/f-lux-%E2%80%98natural-lighting%E2%80%99-for-ubuntu-gets-an-indicator-applet-updated/ Just thought I would mention as we are talking about the subject.