# Can't change brightness on Packard Bell LM86

Tags: 10.10, brightness

I got a Packard Bell EasyNote LM86 and the problem is I cannot set the brightness. I have tried with both the hotkeys which is <kbd>Fn</kbd> and either <kbd>F11</kbd> to turn down and <kbd>F12</kbd> to turn up. I have also tried through the command line by doing

```
echo 50 > /proc/...
```

and also tried through the GNOME brightness applet.

Comment: just answered a question about something similar http://askubuntu.com/questions/24812/how-to-activate-notebook-function-keys/24824#24824 don't know if its what you are looking for.

Comment: @Allan no didnt help, any other ideas?

Comment: found a forum post here http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1500505 about the same laptop with the same problem. Unfortunately no one posted to say if there was a solution that ticks me off you might want to pm the user that started the post to find out if they found a solution in the end.

Comment: I managed to fix the issue using this ppa, https://launchpad.net/~kamalmostafa/+archive/linux-kamal-mjgbacklight

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fix the problem by using [this PPA](https://launchpad.net/~kamalmostafa/+archive/linux-kamal-mjgbacklight)  and setting `acpi_backlight=vendor` as a boot parameter.

Comment: You should accept this answer so that the question is marked as answered.  Also, it's just The Way The Site Works™.

Answer (score 0):

I have a Packard Bell EasyNote TJ68  and this fix worked for me.

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/default/grub
```

Change the line `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""` into

```
 GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="acpi_osi=Linux"
```

save, exit, and run

```
sudo update-grub
```

Restart your system

[Source](http://livinginjava.blogspot.com/2010/11/ubuntu-1010-brightness-problem-in-acer.html)

Answer (score 0):

### Same solution as one-liner

For this solution no `nano` knowledge is required. It is also handy for multi-machine installation scripts.

```
sudo sed -i 's|^GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"|GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi=Linux"|' /etc/default/grub && sudo update-grub
```